# How to make templateString dynamic in StrSubstitutor

Tags: java, arrays, apache-commons-lang, apache-commons-lang3

```
String[] greetings = {"Hello1", "Hello2", "Hello3"};  
String otherString = "green";
Map<String, String[]> valuesMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
valuesMap.put("greeting", greetings);
valuesMap.put("color", otherString );

String templateString = "Its ${color} around. ${greeting} StrSubstitutor APIs.";
StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap);
String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);
```

I am looking for output similar to:

```
Its green around. Hello1 StrSubstitutor APIs.
or Hello2 StrSubstitutor APIs
or Hello3 StrSubstitutor APIs.
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Just iterate over your array?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Edited with more input.
Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: But your variable part is the array of greetings. How should the StrSubstitutor know how much Strings he has to replace/create. You have to iterate over the String[] and execute for each element the Substituor

Comment: Agree, but is there a way to tell StrSubstitutor to iterate for array variable?

Comment: I guess you didn't get how the `StrSubstitutor` works. You gave it a `Map` and a `String`, it parses the `String` and if it finds any match with a key from the `Map` it will be replaced by the value of this key. So it's up to you to give the right params. In your example the `StrSubstituor` will always replace greetings with a String representation of your array. Pls read the docs for more info: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html

Comment: Yes I understand this. I guess I need to iterate over greetings[] array and keep on appending to a TEMP string and finally substitute using StrSubstitutor.

Comment: This sounds right. Please provide your working code in the end.

Comment: How are you putting a String object in  `Map<String, String[]>` ? I dont think `valuesMap.put("color", otherString );` will compile